# CSV Writer (Python) with CRLF instead of LF

Tags: python, csv, csvreader, csvwriter

Hi I am trying to use `csv` library to convert my CSV file into a new one.

The code that I wrote is the following:

```py
import csv
import re

file_read=r'C:\Users\Comarch\Desktop\Test.csv'
file_write=r'C:\Users\Comarch\Desktop\Test_new.csv'

def find_txt_in_parentheses(cell_txt):
    pattern = r'\(.+\)'
    return set(re.findall(pattern, cell_txt))

with open(file_write, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file_w:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file_w, lineterminator="\n")
    with open(file_read, 'r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as file_r:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file_r)
        for row in csv_reader:
            cell_txt = row[0]
            txt_in_parentheses = find_txt_in_parentheses(cell_txt)
            if len(txt_in_parentheses) == 1:
                txt_in_parentheses = txt_in_parentheses.pop()
                cell_txt_new = cell_txt.replace(' ' + txt_in_parentheses,'')
                cell_txt_new = txt_in_parentheses + '\n' + cell_txt_new
                row[0] = cell_txt_new
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

The only problem is that in the resulting file (**Test_new.csv** file), I have `CRLF` instead of `LF`.
Here is a sample image of:

- read file on the left
- write file on the right:

[image]

And as a result when I copy the csv column into Google docs Excel file I am getting a blank line after each row with `CRLF`.

[image]

Is it possible to write my code with the use of `csv` library so that `LF` is left inside a cell instead of `CRLF`.

Comment: You *really* should not mix `CRLF` and `LF` in text files. Use one, or the other. Your input file is already practically broken. If the system you are creating this file for can not deal with `CRLF` for some reason, your best bet is probably to use `LF` all the way.

Comment: @Tomalak
The problem is I did not mix it. This is what I got from Microsoft Excel after saving the file as CSV file.

Comment: Interesting, I've never known! But I can reproduce it, Excel saves `LF` only for me as well. What trouble does it cause when you leave it at `CRLF` after your change? (Excel itself is not confused by it, it opens both files just fine for me.)

Comment: @Tomalak
I have edited the question and added a screen of what I got in Google Docs Excel.
A blank line in a cell after each line ending with `CRLF` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation of `csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

> If `csvfile` is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`<sup>1</sup>
> [...]
>
> **Footnotes**
>
> <sup>1(1,2)</sup>
> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling.

This is precisely the issue you're seeing. So...

```
with open(file_read, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file_r, \
     open(file_write, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file_w:
     
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_r, dialect='excel')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file_w, dialect='excel')

    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I was on this site but I did not go to the very bottom of the page and this is why I missed this part. Learned a new lesson: Read the docs until the end :)

Comment: @JohnSnow I've simply gotten into the habit of always opening CSV files with `newline=''`, but I've never fully realized *why*. Now I know. :)

Comment: So we have helped each other :) This is good :)

Answer (score 0):

You are on Windows, and you open the file with mode 'w' -- which gives you windows style line endings. Using mode 'wb' should give you the preferred behaviour.

Comment: `wb` means that the OP has to take care of text encoding manually, so just switching to `wb` and not doing anything else is asking for trouble at another point.